# Changing one byte in a file in C

Tags: c

I have a file stream open and ready.

How do I access and change a single Byte in the stream such that the change is reflected on the file?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("so-data.dat", "r+b"); // Error checking omitted
    fseek(f, 5, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite("x", 1, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: A (f != NULL) is required. fclose(NULL) invokes UB.

Comment: fwrite("x", 1, 1, f);

Doesn't this write the first byte of the address of the string "x"?

Comment: No, it doesn't - ignore me :-)

Comment: Doesn't the r+ permission disallow writing?

Comment: @cletus: Then what "r" is expected to do? "r+" is read/write.

Comment: Note that jumping to computed locations in a *text* mode file is implementation defined. For a platform where text and binary modes are different (i.e., almost everything except Unix), you'll need to handle the fact that newlines can be multiple bytes (or otherwise funny). Whether this matters to Yuval A I don't know.

Comment: @liw.fi: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-writen-in-binary-and-text-mode ; I'd recommend to always open files in binary mode by default so you can be sure that what you see is what you get

Answer (score 5):

```
FILE* fileHandle = fopen("filename", "r+b"); // r+ if you need char mode
fseek(fileHandle, position_of_byte, SEEK_SET);
fwrite("R" /* the value to replace with */, 1, 1, fileHandle);
```

Comment: "rw" truncates the file. You need "rb".

Comment: sizeof(char) == 1, by definition.

Comment: @Greg, on POSIX systems (Linux included) "r+" will do and "b" is ignored. Sadly, on Windows you have to include "b" for binary mode.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h> /* standard header, use the angle brackets */

int main(void)
{
    char somechar = 'x'; /* one-byte data */
    FILE* fp = fopen("so-data.txt", "r+");
    if (fp) {
      fseek(fp, 5, SEEK_SET);
      fwrite(&somechar, 1, 1, fp);
      fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0; /* if you are on non-C99 systems */
}
```