# File size not equal to memory size?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write-to-disk an array containing 11.26 million uint16_t values. The total memory size should be ~22 MB. However, the size of my file is 52MB. I'm using fprintf to write the array to disk. I thought maybe the values were being promoted. I tried to be explicit but it seems to make no difference. The size of my file is stubbornly unchanged.

What am I doing wrong? Code follows.

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
...
uint32_t dbsize = 11262336;
uint16_t* db_ = new uint16_t[dbsize_];
...
char fname[256] = "foo";

FILE* f = fopen(fname, "wb");
if(f == NULL) 
{
    return;
}

fprintf(f, "%i\t", dbsize_);
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < dbsize_; i++)
{
    fprintf(f, "%" SCNu16 "", db_[i]);
}
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Did you open your file? It should be surprisingly readable in a text editor (unless there's something non-standard behind that SCNu16 macro).

Comment: Hi Mat. Notice I write a binary file. I did not try to inspect it through a hex editor.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to point out. Open it in a text editor.

Comment: So you know that the contents of your file are incorrect, but you didn't even look at what it's in there. Wow.

Comment: Saving memory content in text format will always make it larger.

Comment: @Daniel - required reading:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-writen-in-binary-and-text-mode?rq=1

Comment: Jon: that's not very helpful. I already said the file is written in binary. It's gibberish. I'm working from the command line. I do not have a hex editor handy. I shouldn't need one for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Daniel `fprintf` doesn't print out binary, it prints out text. That's what Mat and Jon are suggesting.

Comment: @Daniel You don't need hex editor. Open it with text editor such as Notepad and vim.

Comment: `fprintf` writes whatever you pass as printf-style text, regardless of how you opened the file. `fwrite` writes what you pass in directly, without pretty-printing. I think you want `fwrite`.

Comment: @Daniel: Or use `head`, since you're at the command line.

Comment: @Daniel: You have a huge misconception here then. If you want ascii, then your assumption as of what the file size should be is completely wrong. `unint16_t` range from `0` to `65535`, so each single element in the array will take anywhere from 1 to 5 characters. If the distribution is random it will take on average 5 characters (rounding). Add the separator and you get 6 chars per number. 11 millions times 6 characters amounts to roughly 60M. The file is smaller as your data distribution seems to be offsetted a bit towards the low numbers.

Comment: @David Have you just discovered a fault in his random number generator? Or some fraud going on?

Comment: @chepner  `(10 * 1 + 90 * 2 + 900 * 3 + 9000 * 4 + 55536 * 5) / 65536 = 4.830474853515625` It's 5, not 2.5.

Comment: @chepner: Is it? There are 10000 numbers with < 5 characters, while there are 64535 numbers with 5 characters in the range 0..65535. The exact number is lower than 5, but closer to 5 than 4

Comment: Thank you folks. Your input has been much appreciated.

Comment: jonchen, David: mea culpa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're writing ASCII to your file, not binary.

Try writing your array like this instead of using `fprintf` in a loop.

```
fwrite(db_, sizeof(db_[0]), dbsize, f);
```

`fprintf` always formats numbers and other types to text, whether you've opened the file in binary mode or not. Binary mode just keeps the runtime from doing things like converting `\n` to `\r\n`.

Comment: Hero! Thank you Collin. Sorry about the ninja edit to my post. I realised I mixed up two variables when pasting (db_ and dbsize_).

Comment: BTW, is there any good online resource that discusses these issues?

Comment: @Daniel I guess you could check out the docs for [`<stdio.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf` will convert you number to a series of ASCII characters and write them to a file. Depending on its value, a 32-bit int will be from 1 to 10 characters long when expressed as a string. You need to use `fwrite` to write raw binary values to a file.

Answer (score 2):

The source of confusion is likely to be that the "b" in `FILE* f = fopen(fname, "wb");` [does not do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-writen-in-binary-and-text-mode?rq=1).

Most significantly, it doesn't change any of the print or scan statements to use binary values instead of ASCII values.  Like others have said - use `fwrite` instead.