# '^M' character inserted instead of new line

Tags: c, tftp

**Goal:**
Transferring a file from client to the server.

**Environment:** Linux

**Problem:**

1. When opening the incompletely copied file in the server, it looks like there is a "^M" character in the place of new line.

Comment: Check whether the variable newLen is 512 for every read operation and write operation.

Comment: it is because I have an else if statement that catches that if it is not.

Comment: Use newLen != 512 instead of newLen < 512. Also use BYTE buffer instead of char buffer.

Comment: Any Idea about the new line issue?

Comment: open file with binary(b) mode

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? I am not too familiar with File I/O in C.

Comment: go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-writen-in-binary-and-text-mode

Answer (score 0):

^M (one character) is 0x0D

NewLine char on Linux is 0x0A

NewLine char on Windows is 0x0D 0x0A (2 characters)

So 0x0D,0x0A will be displayed as ^M,NewLine (depends on which editor you use, what I said is correct with VIM)

BTW, if you want to input a ^M, you need to press ctrl+v, then ctrl+m (In VIM)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary mode. In text mode newline is represented as /r/n.