# Alternate between fwrite and fprintf on same file

Tags: c, file-io, bin

Is it possible to alternate writing between binary and regular writes on the same file?

Would i just need to keep opening and closing the file like so?

```
struct node x;
FILE* fout;
fout = fopen("output.bin", "wb");
fwrite(&x, sizeof(struct node), 1, fout);
fclose(fout);
fout = fopen("output.bin", "a");
fprintf("&d", x.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as mixing on POSIX systems: Both of these are buffered stdio routines within the same library, and on POSIX (UNIX/Linux/Solaris/BSD) OS there is no difference between binary and text mode, so you can indeed mix them.

Typically fprintf will trigger flushes after each newline so as long as you aren't mixing `fprintf/fwrite` with direct `write()` you should be fine.

Regarding Windows: fopen supports the "b" mode, and there is indeed a difference. If a file is open in text mode, fseek will be limited to the beginning or current file pointer. I don't pretend to know if there would be any pitfalls using fprintf() in binary mode so I recommend you to check previous SO threads if Windows is your concern.

[Difference between files writen in binary and text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-writen-in-binary-and-text-mode)

Normally if I need to mix in formatted output with binary I use sprintf() or some other in memory mechanism to write to a buffer first, and then bulk write (flush) the buffered data with fwrite().

Comment: There is also the `_setmode` function that is specific to Windows. That would allow you to switch between binary and text I/O.

Comment: I doubt that there are differences in buffering between `fprintf` and `fwrite`, I think that's soley related to the stream where these functions are applied to.