# Concatenate files using the binary read and write

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a program which takes n number of files and then the user will input their names of the files and then my program will concatenate all those files into 1 file separated by a new-line, here is my program (which works okay):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin>>n;

    ifstream read;
    ofstream finalout;
    int i;
    finalout.open("concatn.txt");
    if(!finalout)
    {
        cout << "Oops something went wrong, SORRY DUDE" << endl;
    }
    char a[n][50];
    char help[50];

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       scanf("%s", help);
       strcpy(a[i], help);
    }

    string STRING;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        read.open(a[i]);
        if(read == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Could not open the file, SORRY DUDE" << endl;
        }
        while(read.eof() == 0)
        {
            getline(read, STRING);
            finalout << STRING;
        }
        finalout << "\n";
        read.close();
        read.clear();
    }

    finalout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I have to do the same thing but using the "BINARY READ AND WRITE" but my output file should still be a txt file, how can I do that and can someone explain what does that really mean beacuse I am a bit confused !?

Comment: A) `char a[n][50];` this is a non-portable extension of your compiler, VLAs are not standard B) If you have something that works why do you "need to do the same thing using BINARY READ AND WRITE" ? C) [Difference between files writen in binary and text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229924/583833)

Comment: Its part of my assigment for homework that's why :), and the link you suggested is for C, I need a CPP implementation I guess

Comment: `finalout << read.rdbuf();` will write all the contents of `read` into `finalout` in one call. No need for any loop.

Comment: After `cout << "Oops something went wrong, SORRY DUDE" << endl;` should you do a return/exit? i.e. no point carrying on

Comment: `while(read.eof() == 0)` is bound to be wrong - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @EdHeal Yes of course, I mean I know that but I am focused on the binary thing first and then I ll add to everything the exit codes etc, but it seems like everybody is giving me feedback on this code instead of telling me something for my actual question :/

Comment: Read up http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ and the write version

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` in C++ code? `cin` exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary read-write is just to support `plateform-independent` read-write support. For example, on Windows platform `New Line` is `\r\n` but for UNIX based platform it is just `\n`. So, When we are reading in *binary mode* the characters will be read *as it is*. But if you are reading it in *non binary mode* then characters will be modified if needed.

To open a file in binary mode use `ios::binary` flag.

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

See [here for more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)