# Why does fwrite write 9 bytes for some doubles?

Tags: c, double, fwrite

I need to write some C code that writes doubles out to file.

For some values, fwrite writes the correct 8-byte binary to file. For other values, it seems to prepend an extra 9th byte. For example, this code writes 9 bytes comprising x0d, followed by the correct 8 bytes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

int main()
{
    // Generate a number
    double x = -3.0 * cos(PI * 5.0 / 8.0);
    printf("%.*e\n", DECIMAL_DIG, x);

    // Uncomment this to get an 8-byte file instead of 9
    // x = (float) x;

    // Write number to file
    FILE* fw = fopen("out.bin", "w");
    if (fw != NULL)
    {
        size_t Nw = fwrite(&x, sizeof(double), 1, fw);
        printf("Wrote %i values to file.\n", Nw);

        if (fclose(fw) != 0)
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

However, if I change the value, for example to `double x = -3.0 * cos(PI * 3.0 / 8.0);`, or even if I just cast the number to float and back again (see "Uncomment this..." in the above code), then the correct 8 bytes are written.

I am compiling with MinGW GCC-6.3.0-1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between files written in binary and text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229924/difference-between-files-written-in-binary-and-text-mode)

Comment: @Harry the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2017) is preferable to googling.

Comment: @WeatherVane To be honest, even on that man page, the access mode modifiers are pretty well hidden! But you're right, at least they're there.

Comment: @Harry there are four paragraphs about the mode, including "If **t** or **b** is not given in *mode*, the default translation mode is defined by the global variable `_fmode`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You opened the file in text mode, and are writing binary data to it.  Windows changes <kbd>LF</kbd> `0x0a` to <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> `0x0d 0x0a`.  You need to use "wb" as the 2nd argument when opening the file.

Comment: Thank you. The first result in google only listed "r", "w", "a", "r+", "w+" and "a+". Ahhh, that explains why it was only happening for some specific values! I'm surprised that "text mode" is the default.